# Duplicated params for post request in Guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle6, guzzle

Some API's requires multiple duplicate param in POST Request. 
It looks like this:

```
curl -X POST https://api.freenom.com/v2/domain/register\
-d “domainname=TEST001.TK\
&nameserver=NS1.TEST001.TK\
&nameserver=NS2.TEST001.TK\
&domaintype=PAID”
```

With Guzzle, I try to do smth. like this:

```
$this->client->post($this->apiUrl . 'domain/register', ['form_params' => ['nameserver' => ['ns1.com', 'ns2.com']]])
```

but it doesn't work.
Maybe I can specify form_data like string instead of array, but I haven't found any solution how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw `body` instead of `form_params` to pass request body as a string directly. In this case you can create the string however you want.

Comment: In newest version you have to use `multipart` instead `body`.  
_Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or a the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request._

Comment: It's depends on your use case. `body` is the correct way if you need to pass an arbitrary string, and `multipart` is used to build a complex body from an array. Different use cases.